# How to analyse sh files in Sonar?

Tags: shell, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I need to analyse the shell scripts using the Sonar server.

The files that I have are of extension sh and would need to be analysed. But I don't see any plugin for the sh from the Sonar plugins.

Comment: You can download http://www.shellcheck.net/about.html, intall it on your server and run it inside a "Execute Shell Build Step" for the task

Comment: thanks, could you give me more detail on how i can configure in my sonar server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your .sh files are bash scripts or some approximate equivalent then you can't currently configure your SonarQube server to analyze them because there's no plugin that handles such scripting.

**Sept 2018 Update**

There's now a plugin in the Marketplace to read in i-Code CNES reports. i-Code CNES covers two flavors of Fortran *and* Shell.

Comment: any plans on creating such, especially checking the shebang and checking for POSIX sh, GNU bash, and the Korn Shell (AT&T ksh88, ksh93, and mksh) dialects?

Comment: Not in our plans @dokaspar. Feel free to initiate your own analyzer & ping the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) when you have specific development questions. :D